# How do I simulate a PUT form in ZF2?

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2

I'm implementing a REST service with Zend Framework 2. The routing and controller works very well, but now I need to display an update form in the view.

In Zend Framework 1 I could simply do a POST with the "magic" GET parameter `?_method=PUT`, which would make ZF think it was actually a PUT request. Meaning the form tag looked something like:

```
<form action="/resource/1/?_method=PUT" method="POST">
```

The above doesn't work in ZF2: Instead of running the `update()` method in my controller the `create()` method is exectued.

How do I simulate a PUT request in ZF2? Can I do it without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ZF2 doesn't handle the situation like yours at all. You have to handle it by yourself. See the code below:

```
class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
          $event->getApplication()
                ->getEventManager()
                ->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function(MvcEvent $e){
                    $request = $e->getRequest();
                    $m = $request->getQuery('_method');

                    switch ($m)
                    {
                        case Request::METHOD_PUT:
                            $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_PUT);
                            break;
                        case Request::METHOD_DELETE:
                            $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_DELETE);
                            break;
                        case Request::METHOD_POST:
                            $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_POST);
                            break;
                        case Request::METHOD_GET:
                            $request->setMethod(Request::METHOD_GET);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, since it will actually do what I asked in the question ("simulate a PUT request"). Marking as correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Once again I'm answering my own question.

The "magic" is gone from ZF2, we need to fix things ourselves. This is how I did it:

```
class ResourceController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addHttpMethodHandler('POST', array($this, 'handlePostPut'));
    }

    public function handlePostPut($event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ('put' == strtolower($request->getQuery('_method'))) {
            $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();

            $id   = $this->getIdentifier($routeMatch, $request);
            $data = $this->processBodyContent($request);

            if ($id !== false) {
                return $this->update($id, $data);
            }

            return $this->replaceList($data);
        } else {
            return $this->processPostData($request);
        }
    }
}
```

The key is the `addHttpMethodHandler()` method in the `AbstractRestfulController` class. With this we can override which controller function is being run for a specific HTTP method. In this case I'm overriding the POST method to call my `handlePostPut()` function instead. In that function I'm checking whether my "magic" query parameter is present, and if so I'm just doing what the controller would have done if it was a put request. Otherwise I'm treating it as a normal POST request.

There is one caveat though: The action parameter in the RouteMatch object will be set to `post` even if we're treating it as a put. I don't know of a good way to fix that at the moment.

Comment: It's a nice solution. I've just offered mine in more generic way.